# How can i avoid skipping rows when i use select * from table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, cmd

I want to check if everything is on the table but using the command

```
select * from table_name
```

Some of the rows are skipped(skipping) because they are so many. How can i see them all?

Comment: Where are u using the query?

Comment: dude,if you are using postgresql as you tagged. i think you can just open the terminal, use postgres -U xxx -d xxx -p xxx to enter the postgresql and doing the query you can just see all

Comment: i am in psql and i can see the start and the end but somewhere in the middle it sais skipping and i can't see...

Comment: what is the output of `select count(*) from table_name;`  and it is match with actual rows number.

Comment: Add a screenshot to the question

Answer (score 1):

In [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) it is possible to pipe the query output to a file:

```
=> \o 'query-result.txt'
=> select * from t;
```

Now open the file in your favorite text editor

A second `\o` will turn the output back to the terminal